# calculate two columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, calculated-columns

I have a MySQL database, where I have 3 columns:

```
Day_hours
Day_minutes
All_day_hours
```

I am gonna have some different form fields in a JSP page, where I can put in how many hours I work. On a day I work in different places, that means that I need fx to put in `5 * Day_hours, Day_minutes and All_day_hours`. So the problem is that I want to calculate all the hours and minutes during a day. So if I fx worked:

```
1 job: 2 hours 15 minutes
2 job: 3 hours 45 minutes
3 job: 1 hours 10 minutes
4 job: 4 hours 40 minutes
5 job: 3 hours 15 minutes
```

So that means if I calculate the column "Day_minutes" it would give me the result 125. I would like that the 125 minutes is converted to hours, so the result would be 2 hours and 5 minutes. Afterwords the Day_hours and Day_minutes have to be addéd to the column Allday_hours. So Allday_hours is the sum of Day_hours + Day_minutes

so Fx in MySQL database there is the following information for an example day:

```
                Day_hours      Day_minutes       Allday_hours
1 job                  2              15               2.15
2 job:                 3              45               3.45
3 job:                 1              10               1.10
4 job:                 4              40               4.40
5 job:                 3              15               3.15
```

So my question is, how do I calculate the Day_hours and Day_minutes to the Allday_hours, so the result in job 1 would be 2.15?

Have a good weekend.

Best Regards
Mads

Comment: I am not understand your question

Comment: Have you tried to use UDF on the computed column, and do the processing/calculation in the function?

Comment: Hello. Thanks a lot for your answers. I just edited my question, so it is more clear. Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not save something in `Allday_hours` as this is redundant information.

You can retrieve the data you want always (without problems) from the data you have. For example with

```
SELECT *, ((Day_hours*60 + Day_minutes)/60) AS Allday_hours FROM timedata...
```

No need to actually save them.

By the way I think it is rather odd that 2 hours plus 15 minutes add up to something like `2.15`. So my query above computes something relative... if you really want to compute your value, you might use

```
SELECT *, (Day_hours + (Day_minutes / 100)) as Allday_hours FROM timedata
```

And if you really want to save this, you can use the calculations in an update statement like

```
UPDATE timedata SET Allday_hours = (Day_hours + (Day_minutes / 100))
```

Comment: It Works like a charm GhostHandler. Thanks a lot. Just a last question. Why is it you divide by 100? :-/

Comment: If you have 2 hours and 15 minutes you want to get 2.15. If you divide 15/100 you get 0.15. If you add 2+0.15 you get 2.15.

Comment: If I shouldn't use the Allday_hours how should the syntax be then? I am thinking of if I calculate it only with Day_hours and Day_minutes without saving those two together in Allday_hours

Comment: I would use the first statement.